# What is the meaning of "shower night" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "shower night" in the following sentence?

> As you know, freshman year the big exam is the freshman physics exam and their **shower night** with Burton Third Bombers you know there's always special events that happen during shower night in addition to just getting showers... um they get this big blue whale...

For clarity, you can see the following YouTube video:

[Tea with Evelyn Wang](https://youtu.be/ylXcZguGS1g?t=102) from the "Tea with Teachers" channel.

Comment: hard to be sure without enough context, but the most likely common meaning is "the night they take a shower", implying that they do not shower every day.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid more context is needed to construct meaning. That's not a sentence, just a phrase, and the pronoun "their" must refer to some noun that isn't present.

Comment: From http://tech.mit.edu/V120/N45/col45veena.45c.html *Freshman shower night, traditionally the evening before the first 8.01 exam, is one of those vaunted MIT traditions passed down through the years. On the night in question, upperclassmen throw freshmen, kicking and screaming, into a waiting shower. Upon emerging, drenched, the freshmen attempt to retaliate against the upperclassmen by forcing them into the shower. In the end, some are happy, some are miserable, and everyone ends up wet and cold.* And "The Burton Third Bombers" are here https://bc.mit.edu/floors/burton-3rd

Comment: @Hellion Verging on the studentist.

Comment: @ColleenV, any reason you didn't make that an answer?

Comment: @Marthaª Because the question was closed at the time I commented, and I expected it to stay closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ColleenV commented, quoting an (apparently since-deleted) page on the MIT website:

> Freshman shower night, traditionally the evening before the first 8.01 exam, is one of those vaunted MIT traditions passed down through the years. On the night in question, upperclassmen throw freshmen, kicking and screaming, into a waiting shower. Upon emerging, drenched, the freshmen attempt to retaliate against the upperclassmen by forcing them into the shower. In the end, some are happy, some are miserable, and everyone ends up wet and cold.

(As of July 2023, the page is preserved [at The Internet Archive Wayback Machine site](https://web.archive.org/web/20161028083642/http://tech.mit.edu/V120/N45/col45veena.45c.html).)

Comment: I lived on Burton 2nd in 1967 and agree with this answer.